# Display first Word in String with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, split

I'm using ruby on rails and I want to display only first word of string.

My broken code: `<%= @user.name %>` displaying `Barack Obama`.

I would want to have it display `Barack` and in other place `Obama`.

How can I split it and display it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short and readable:

```
name = "Obama Barack Hussein"
puts "#{name.partition(" ").first} - #{name.partition(" ").last}"
# Obama - Barack Hussein
```

and if the order of the first and  lastname is reversed

```
name = "Barack Hussein Obama"
puts "#{name.rpartition(" ").last} - #{name.rpartition(" ").first}"
# Obama - Barack Hussein
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `Enumerable#partition`. Maybe somebody (maybe me!) could benchmark to compare it to `String#split` for this use-case... :)

Answer (score 50):

```
> "this is ruby".split.first
#=> "this"
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets said you have:

```
string = "Barack Obama"
split_string = string.split()
```

In ruby documentation:

> If pattern is omitted, the value of $; is used. If $; is nil (which is
>   the default), str is split on whitespace as if ` ‘ were specified.

after that use `split_string[0] # ==> Barack` ou `split_string[1] # ==> Obama`

Answer (score 1):

You can simple:

```
# `split` default is split by space `' '`
<%= @user.name.split.first %>
```

I recommend [further reading](http://objectsonrails.com/) about [decorators](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) where you can define a method like (or you can rely on a helper as well):

```
# It will give you 'Barack'
def first_name
  name.split.first
end

# It will give you 'Obama'
def last_name
  name.split.last
end
```